# Ubuntu Multipass snap instance has somebody's ssh key in authorized_keys file

Tags: ssh, nextcloud, multipass

I just discovered multipass today. In my first instance (nextcloud), on a local machine I was suprised to find a key for ubuntu@localhost in /writeable/user-something/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Is it supposed to be there for a good reason?

I'm struggling to visualize a world where it isn't concerning.